# How can I properly clean unused threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have a client software (on Android) that listens to incoming messages. The messages are received in a while loop that waits for messages to come. When a message is found, it updates the GUI. [Since in Android, GUI can not be updated directly ]  A thread is called to do this. My problem is, if there are many messages, results in many threads! And it creates a clumsy situation. My abstract code is,

```
My_Client()
{
  send_text_function() // My question is not about it
  in_a_thread_Call_receive_from_others_function() [see 1]
}

receiving_funtion() // [this function is mentioned above as (see 1), called in a thread]
{
  while( waiting for new message)
  {
    >>A new message found >> create a thread to update the GUI.  // << Here is my question. see 2
  //android.os.Handler.thread type thread!
  } 
}
```

label 2: Now this thread is created each time there is a message. How can I just create one thread and keep using it again and again? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html).
2. In the [run()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) method of the Thread create a new [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).
3. When you want to do something on the target thread, use the Handler's [post()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

You can create a Handler on the Main thread to post-back operations that update the GUI.

Also consider using [AsyncTask<>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).